# Jest Your test suite must contain at least one test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I have a simple test file in `./pages/test.js`

```
import React from 'react'

export default function HomePage () {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Testing Next.js With Jest and React Testing Library</h1>
    </main>
  )
}
```

In `./test/pages/index.test.js` I made the following simple test to check if my page is rendering properly and if it has a heading

```
import React from 'react'
// Using render and screen from test-utils.js instead of
// @testing-library/react
import { render, screen } from '../test-utils'
import HomePage from '../../pages/test'

describe('HomePage', () => {
  it('should render the heading', () => {
    render(<HomePage />)

    const heading = screen.getByText('Testing Next.js With Jest and React Testing Library')

    // we can only use toBeInTheDocument because it was imported
    // in the jest.setup.js and configured in jest.config.js
    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

After running the test, I get the following error

```
 FAIL  pages/test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:304:17
      at node_modules/emittery/index.js:260:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Emittery.Typed.emit (node_modules/emittery/index.js:258:23)

 PASS  test/pages/index.test.js

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
```

Why does jest say I am missing a test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does jest say I am missing a test?

Because Jest thinks `pages/test.js` is a test file. Jest uses the following regex to detect test files.

```
(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$
```

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring),

> By default it looks for `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` files inside of `__tests__` folders, as well as any files with a suffix of `.test` or `.spec` (e.g. `Component.test.js` or `Component.spec.js`). It will also find files called `test.js` or `spec.js`.

A simple solution would be to rename the file.

Comment: I renamed `test.js` to `simple.js`. I then moved the file so its location is `./pages/__tests__/simple.js`. After changing the `HomePage ` import to `import HomePage from '../../pages/__tests__/simple` I run the test and get the same error as above. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @dev_el As I mentioned in the answer, Jest assumes all files inside `__tests__` as test files. Move `simple.js` out of the `__tests__` directory.

Comment: thank you so much, I had my test data in a file in the `__tests__` folder and moving it out of there solved it.